# Custom SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, listview, simplecursoradapter

I am trying to implement a custom SimpleCursorAdapter but the problem is, wen i run my application, the listView does not show anything. Why is that? Here is my code:

```
package com.messageHider;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class myAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {
    private Context appContext;
    private int layout;
    private Cursor mycursor;
    public myAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from,int[] to) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to);
        this.appContext=context;
        this.layout=layout;
        this.mycursor=c;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        return 0;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)appContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView=inflater.inflate(layout, null, true);
        ImageView imageViewVidIcon=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewVidThumb);
        imageViewVidIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.videothumb);
        ImageView imageViewPlayBtn=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewPlaybtn);
        imageViewPlayBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.playbtn);
        TextView textViewTitle=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewVideoTitle);
        String title=mycursor.getString(mycursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME));
        textViewTitle.setText(title);
        imageViewPlayBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(appContext, "It works", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd say your

```
public int getCount() {
        return 0;
    }
```

makes the ListView think there is nothing to view.
Try to

```
return 1;
```

for a start or debug session.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 0;
}
```

This function returns the number of elements in your list.
So it can't be 0 as you returned, it should be the size of your list of elements.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `bindView()` and `newView()` manually in your custom `getView()`. Because in the original source code, `bindView()` and `newView()` are called inside `getView()`, so you also have to do that when you override it.